# Can I delete records from a sql server table in the middle of a while reader.read loop

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am trying to using a SQL data reader to move records from one table into an archive table. I want to do the transfer record-by-record (instead of inserting and deleting en masse) so that if an error occurs, the minimum amount of data is lost (and has to be restored from backup).

My question is, will SQL reader work if I delete records once they are read? This is by far the most simple and direct way to do what I am trying to do. Will it open unexpected errors?

```
While myReader.Read // select * from tableA where older than 1 year record
    insert the record into tableA_archive
    delete the record from tableA   
loop
```

This seems vaguely analogous to looping through a list that you are modifying within the loop--which I know causes all sorts of headaches in .net

```
for aItem in listA
   if aItem fits criteria, send to list B and delete from listA
next
```

Is there any reason not to modify the underlying table while a reader is reading? For instance, does a reader use certain indexes to reach records that might shift if I start deleting records in the middle of the loop?

Comment: Why not just `DELETE FROM tableA OUTPUT deleted.* INTO tableA_archive WHERE Dt <= DATEADD(year,-1,getdate())`?

Comment: @MartinSmith nice, didn't know about the DELETE INTO syntax.

Comment: Consensus seems to be that the best way to do this is to write a SQL server stored procedure that uses a transaction statement. So basically I need two statements in the transaction: insert old records into archive, delete old records from non-archive. The transaction statement will ensure that either both of these statements execute, or neither statement executes. If it hits an error mid-transaction, no insertion/deletion will occur. Correct?

Comment: Also, seems like you need to catch errors in the transaction and specify a rollback or it might keep going http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

Comment: @MartinSmith, that should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid transferring rows all the way down to the client, just to re-upload them back to the server again. Instead, do something like this (within the same transaction):

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE SELECT * FROM OLD_TABLE WHERE condititon;
DELETE FROM OLD_TABLE WHERE condititon;
```

Or even MS SQL Server specific:

```
DELETE FROM OLD_TABLE OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO NEW_TABLE WHERE condition;
```

*(all conditions are same)*

You can even execute these statements from your .NET code if you wish, and still retain the benefit of **not** downloading all the rows.

Comment: Thanks Branko (and @MartinSmith). A query along those lines is running perfectly in the test environment. I want to run it safely, however. Given that it is just one statement, should I run it in a transaction statement? Will SQL server roll it back so that it was never run if it hits an error?

Comment: @akh2103 No self-respecting DBMS (including MS SQL Server) will ever let you execute anything outside of a transaction. Even if you don't start the transaction _explicitly_, the transaction will be started for you _implicitly_ (and even auto-rolled back by your ADO.NET provider if something goes wrong). So yes, you get "all or nothing" behavior for `DELETE FROM OLD_TABLE OUTPUT ...` even if you don't explicitly wrap it into a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it within a transaction. This also is a very good candidate for a SP even though you could do it in the code also. You will have to find out a condition that results in a decent amount of rows (not 1 but may be 100 or 1000 or 10000). Experiment and find out how many can be inserted and deleted in one statement within reasonable time (may be few seconds).

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO tableA_archive (col1, col2)
        SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableA WHERE (SomeCondition)
    DELETE FROM tableA  WHERE (SomeCondition)
COMMIT TRAN
```

SomeCondition could be a date range (say a day, an hr etc).

Then run this process in a loop changing the SomeCondition until there is nothing to be backed up. Since this is within a transaction, both insert and delete would either succeed or fail.

Regardless of how many you want to delete in one, if you are concerned about the consistancy, you have to do it within a transaction.

Comment: You should specify the correct isolation level for this technique (REPEATABLE READ).  The default (READ COMMITTED) could result in the SELECT statement retrieving different rows than the DELETE statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should spend some time reading about [transactional isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29), specifically repeatable reads.

In SQL Server, a select statement (which backs your reader) executes (by default) in READ COMMITTED isolation, which means that your delete command will be able to delete rows after they are read, but the *set of the rows that the reader reads* cannot be modified by a delete statement while the select statement is executing.

For what it is worth, moving data from one table to another should generally be done in SQL, not in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

There are several way on these, first you have to understand what is **transaction isolation** 
in SQL server and when do you need to use that.

In your case, seems like you are moving historical data to another table, so using SQL Stored Procedure within transaction scope(with rollback trans) would be worth it.